# Add the duplicate suggestion feature to mobile theme

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, mobile-web, duplicate-suggestions

I noticed this issue as I tend to view Stack Overflow via the mobile site frequently:

The mobile version does not show possible duplicate questions while you're typing the question/description, while in "full site mode" the suggestions come up just fine.

In my mind, getting the suggestions to show up on the mobile version of the site should not be a hard thing to implement

While I admit it makes me lazy asking for this feature when there is a work around, the full site doesn't display nearly as well as the mobile one so it would make life a lot easier to have this simple change.

Also, what good programmer isn't lazy? :)

Comment: Is it really a good idea to be posting questions from a mobile?

Comment: @Mysticial - why not. Can't sleep so I'm reading code in bed, not gonna risk waking the wife with the laptop so the mobile device seems like my best bet. Just wish it worked cleaner.

Comment: if it would happen than its very helpful ...